# jquery delay altering css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, delay

I am trying to reset some css but with a delay after the click. For some reason the delay seems to be getting ignored. Any ideas?

```
$("#closeMe").live("click", function() {
    $("#selectContainer").fadeOut( function() {
        scrollerPos = 1
        $(".scroller").delay(3000).css({"margin-left":"0px"});
        $("#selectContainer img").delay(3000).css({"background-color":"#FFF"});
        $("#selectContainer img:eq(0)").delay(3000).css({"background-color":"#000"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe `css` participates in the effect stuff, so it won't be aware of the queue. From the [`delay` docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of `.show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue.

Pretty sure `css` is on that list too.

No problem, though; you can do this:

```
$("#closeMe").live("click", function() {
    $("#selectContainer").fadeOut( function() {
        scrollerPos = 1
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".scroller").css({"margin-left":"0px"});
            $("#selectContainer img")..css({"background-color":"#FFF"});
            $("#selectContainer img:eq(0)").css({"background-color":"#000"});
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `setTimeout()` instead of `.delay()`

```
setTimeout(resetCSS, 3000);

function resetCSS() {
    $(".scroller").css({"margin-left":"0px"});
    $("#selectContainer img").css({"background-color":"#FFF"});
    $("#selectContainer img:eq(0)").css({"background-color":"#000"});

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".scroller").css({"margin-left":"0px"});
    $("#selectContainer img").css({"background-color":"#FFF"});
    $("#selectContainer img:eq(0)").css({"background-color":"#000"});
},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

quote from [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

> Only subsequent events **in a queue**
>   are delayed;

the `.css()` method does not use the queue.

You need to use a timeout

```
$("#closeMe").live("click", function() {
    $("#selectContainer").fadeOut( function() {
        scrollerPos = 1
       setTimeout(function(){
              $(".scroller").delay(3000).css({"margin-left":"0px"});
              $("#selectContainer img").delay(3000).css({"background-color":"#FFF"});
              $("#selectContainer img:eq(0)").delay(3000).css({"background-color":"#000"});
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`css` is not an animated function. It cannot be `delay` ed.

You can use [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for that:

```
$(".scroller").delay(3000).animate({"marginLeft":0}, 0);
```

But it only works with numeric properties, not `background-color`. For that you can use [jQuery UI `animate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/):

> The jQuery UI effects core extends the animate function to be able to animate colors as well. It's heavily used by the class transition feature and it's able to color animate the following properties:
>
> backgroundColor
>   borderBottomColor
>   borderLeftColor
>   borderRightColor
>   borderTopColor
>   color
>   outlineColor